# How to make bnlearn and dowhy compatible in jupyter notebook?

Tags: python, pygraphviz, causality, dowhy, py-bnlearn

I am trying to do causal analysis in python and obtain direct and indirect effects using dowhy but the graph/structure is not understandable/complex even after increasing the threshold upto 0.8, while using bnlearn, I am getting the graph clear but not able to calculate direct and indirect effects.

Is there any way to make these two packages compatible to work bnlearn for structure/graph and dowhy to calculate direct and indirect effects considering the graph build by bnlearn?